# JavaScript - The internal JavaScript sort method sorts numeric data - True or False?

Tags: javascript

The internal JavaScript sort method sorts numeric data - True or False?

Comment: Give it a try, type `[3,2,1,11].sort()` in the console or have a look at the [specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.4.11).

Comment: is your question missing "only numeric data", because you could test it by your self.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of the test to test what *you* know?

Comment: I can't believe I asked such a silly question back then. Lol :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If compareFunction is not supplied, elements are sorted by converting them to strings and comparing strings in lexicographic ("dictionary" or "telephone book," not numerical) order. For example, "80" comes before "9" in lexicographic order, but in a numeric sort 9 comes before 80.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

So the answer is False.

Comment: Well, to be pedantic, it still sorts numeric data.  Just not in the "expected" fashion.

Comment: I can't argue with that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it doesn't sort very well...

```
[3,5,1,5,10,0,99,10,12].sort()
[0, 1, 10, 10, 12, 3, 5, 5, 99]  // result
```

But you can easily make it sort ok:

```
[3,5,1,5,10,0,99,10,12].sort(function(a,b) {return parseInt(a) > parseInt(b)})
[0, 1, 3, 5, 5, 10, 10, 12, 99] // result
```

Comment: The comparison function should return `-1`, `0` or `1`.

Comment: Is there a case where my function yield incorrect results?

Comment: I think it depends on how the algorithm handles equal values. But your function will basically return `0` when `a` is smaller which means that `a` and `b` are equal. The fact that  I cannot find a counter example does not mean that your method will always work ;)

Comment: Technically you're right. But since the question was about sorting numeric values then I think we would be ok with my simple implementation. If one number isn't larger or smaller then those are the same numbers ;)

Comment: Another equally simple and *correct* function would be `function(a, b) { return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b); }`.

Comment: @ Matthew Crumley - now that's great implementation, nice! :)